# How do we use expect in WebdriverIO as a standalone script?

Tags: webdriver-io

WebdriverIO has a sample of using it in a script:

https://webdriver.io/docs/gettingstarted#run-in-a-script

```js
const { remote } = require('webdriverio');

;(async () => {
    const browser = await remote({
        capabilities: {
            browserName: 'chrome'
        }
    })

    await browser.url('https://webdriver.io')

    const apiLink = await browser.$('=API')
    await apiLink.click()

    await browser.saveScreenshot('./screenshot.png')
    await browser.deleteSession()
})()
```

However, there is no mentioning of how we can use `expect`, such as `expect(elementFoo).toHaveText("Hello World")`  How can we have `expect` (and have one of mocha, jasmine, or cucumber like when we set up a webdriverio project using

```sh
npx wdio ./path/to/new/project
```

or is it already possible to use `expect` without using one of those three modules?)

Also, if we used `npx wdio ./path/to/new/project` to create a whole project, the `expect(elementFoo).toHaveText("Hello World")` knows how to wait a few seconds to finally say that it doesn't contain the text, which I am not sure if pure mocha, jasmine, or cucumber has that feature too.

Comment: I suggest just trying it and seeing what happens.

Comment: just trying would get "expect() is not a function"

Comment: If the only reason you want to use `expect()` is to wait for the page to load, then you should use the functionality built into webdriver.io with [`browser.waitUntil()](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/waitUntil) instead.

Comment: no, I want to use `expect()` to expect some element in page has some text content

Comment: `expect()` is a function defined in testing frameworks such as jest and mocha. In order to use their version of this function, you will need to add them as dependencies. However, it is highly unusual to use `expect()` outside of automated tests. Maybe you just need an `if` statement?

Comment: It is really simple: they suggested a way to run WebdriverIO as a script, and it is super common to use `expect`: https://webdriver.io/docs/assertion so I wonder how we can use it in the standalone script -- they didn't say how

Comment: The first sentence in the link you just gave states: "The WDIO testrunner comes with a built in assertion library". So you must use the "WDIO testrunner" in order to use `expect()` rather than writing a stand alone script.

Comment: When you say "it is supper common to use `expect`", you leave out one important detail: it is common to use `expect` **in tests**. It is highly unusual to use it outside of a testing environment.